# References for convergent sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came up with the following result from Xu 20212, An iterative approach to quadratic optimization, J. Optim. Theory Appl 116 (2003) 659-678. Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers satisfying the condition

$$ s_{n+1}\le (1-\alpha_n)s_n+\alpha_n\beta_n,n\ge 0$$
where $(\alpha_n),(\beta_n)$ are sequences of real number such that

(i) $(\alpha_n)\subset[0,1]$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n=\infty$.

(ii) $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\beta_n\le 0$ or

(ii')$\sum_n\alpha_n\beta_n$ is convergent.

Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n=0$.

I wonder if there are any other references for special cases of this result. I found several here
[Limit of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140143/limit-of-a-sequence) and [Assuming $0 \leq a_{n+1} \leq c_n a_n + b_n$ (+ other conditions), show $a_n \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754289/assuming-0-leq-a-n1-leq-c-n-a-n-b-n-other-conditions-show-a-n-to). I also remember that there is a Russian book for undergraduate students discussing these types of lemmas, but now I couldn't find it again.

Thanks a lot for any help, comment or discussion.